# Bootstrap modal for Flask login form in the base.html without sending the form in every view function?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, bootstrap-modal

I am pretty new to the Flask framework with Miguel Grinberg's Book, Flask Web Development as my reference. For now i have a view function that handles logins and I have no idea how to efficiently implement this using a modal activated by a login button located on the navbar(bootstrap) since this is handled at domain.com/login. The only solution i can think of as deleting this view and copying the code in every view function which i am sure is not a good solution at all.

```
from .forms import LoginForm
from flask.ext.login import login_user

@auth.route('/login/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form=LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user =  User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is not None and user.verify_password(form.password.data):
            login_user(user, form.remember_me.data)
            flash("login success")
            return url_for(".index",username=user.username))
        flash("Invalid username or password.")
    return render_template('auth/login.html',form=form)
```

Comment: So make a modal using `bootstrap` and add `form` to it.submit form using `ajax` request to some `route` with only `post method` in it. Do some checking with the form values and if all values are okay then route to some page or else specify the error and return that error through python. Now in ajax request check the error is there or not . If there then using `Jquery` update the modal. Hope this helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a modal and to the `action` attribute of the form you pass the route to your handler function `/login/`. Something like so:

```
<div class="modal hide" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
    <h3>Login to MyWebsite.com</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form method="post" action='/login/' name="login_form">
      <p><input type="text" class="span3" name="eid" id="email" placeholder="Email"></p>
      <p><input type="password" class="span3" name="passwd" placeholder="Password"></p>
      <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
        <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    New To MyWebsite.com?
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Register</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to make this work by using wtf.quick_forms() though since you don't specify an action?

Comment: You can specify the action as a key parameter passed to the `quick_form()` function: `{{ wtf.quick_form(form, action = "/login") }}`. See [here](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/forms.html) more info on `quick_form()` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax for this.
For example, your login button has class login-js.
Using jquery you could do something like this:

```
$('.login-js').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: '/login/',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.status == 'ok') { //if your response have 'status' key
                   alert('Logged');
                } else {
                   alert('Error.');
                }
            }
        });
})
```

But you'll need to change your view to return json response. I'm not confident how to do this using Flask.